# Is there alternative choice for "Extensive reading for academic success"?

Tags: discussion

"Extensive Reading for Academic Success" is a series of books good for those who are preparing for TOEFL. Each of them includes 80 articles and is much cheaper than other TOEFL books.
But I found that they seem no longer available. Does anyone know other nice books?